# STM32F407ZET6 MCU board freezes when USB 3.0 flash drive is inserted into USB port. (USB 2.0 is fine)

Tags: usb, stm32

I have an inherited code which uses a STM32F407ZET6 MCU with an attached USB-A 2.0 port, the device's purpose is to dump diagnostics data from the device into the USB after prompted by the device menu.

As far as I can tell, the device functions as intended when a USB 2.0 flash drive is inserted into the port. However, the device freezes as soon as a USB 3.0 flash drive is inserted, and remains frozen until hard reset.

Reading online, apparently STM32 USB_OTG only supports USB 2.0? Is that the case, and if not, how do I extend functionality to USB 3.0?

Comment: You probably should add what USB stack software the device is using.  Also, have you used the debugger to see where its halting?  Probably some hard fault, or memory allocation issue or similar.  2.0 vs 3.0 may be misleading, it could be a drive difference aside from that.

Comment: When you mean "USB stack software", are you referring to FS (Fast Speed) and HS (High Speed)?

Comment: No, which USB software is running on MCU? If you generated USB code from CubeIDE, then it's from ST. Which version of USB stack, or other HAL version? Have you tried updating the drivers? Or debugged the code? Any other difference between USB sticks, like size, file system, etc? Where does it get stuck? What have you tried? You can' use USB3 if MCU talks to stick with USB2.

Comment: I am not sure, the software is made on the ARMs IDE, but I think it uses HAL and ST OTG? In regards to the USB sticks, I had received spotty reports of exFAT and NTFS formats can cause the same issues, but I am not sure if that was with drives set in USB 2.0 or USB 3.0.
Only one USB flash drive can be inserted, and the device freezes as soon as the USB flash drive is inserted.
In regards to debugging, I am trying to coax it out, but I am not sure if it even has a debugging mode.

Comment: *Uses HAL/ST OTG USB libraries?
In addition, not sure how relevant this is, but the usb port attached to the device is only designed for USB 2.0, and does not have the additional terminals of USB 3.0